# Running fsck -fy on my mac throws a container write access error. How do I get around this?

Tags: boot, mac, ssd, disk-utility, fsck

My macbook pro is stuck on the Apple logo on booting and after going through most of the alternatives attempts at fixing it, I've finally come to giving the command `fsck -fy` a try. I've booted into safe mode (holding down CMS+S whilst booting) and I've run this command only to get the following error:

```
error: container /dev/rdisk1 is mounted with write access
```

My unix-fu is nowhere near up to the task and I've searched around for similar problems with no success. One thing worth noting is that when the command prompt comes up it says the following:

```
To mount the root device as read-write:
$ /sbin/mount -X /
```

I tried this command thinking that maybe it was something I needed to do before running fsck but it told me that the X option was illegal. Any help greatly appreciated. If this doesn't work at least I can fallback to a reinstall off time machine.

Answer (score 2):

To run `fsck_apfs` as of Big Sur 11.2.3, assuming the container is at `/dev/disk2` and the volume you want to check is at `/dev/disk2s2`:

1. Boot from the recovery partition or external disk (not the disk you want to check).
2. `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/disk2`
3. If the volume is encrypted, `diskutil apfs unlockVolume /dev/disk2s2 -nomount`
4. `fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk2s2`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `fsck -fy` can not repair a filesystem which is currently in use. The filesystem needs to be unmounted or, at the very least, in a "read-only" mode. It may be possible to switch the filesystem to read-only with `/sbin/mount -o remount,ro /`. Then `fsck -fy` might work. As always: make sure you have a backup.

Comment: I tried `umount /dev/rdisk1` and get errors telling me that /dev/rdisk1 is `not a directory or special device` as well as `not currently mounted`. This is despite also being told be fsck that it's mounted with write access. Starting to wonder if it's corrupted

Comment: I also tried `mount -o rdonly /dev/rdisk1` and got the error `unknown special file or file system`. My version of mount didn't accept the remount option.

Comment: This exact method worked for me. There are a number of issues that make this the necessary procedure. (1) fsck from single-user mode now only partly supported, but the same result can be gotten from Recovery console; (2) the container of the volume with problems must be unmounted; (3) fsck for some reason just gave usage messages no matter what was tried--must use fsck_apfs; (4) when run on volume, got message to run on the container. So in place of the step 4 in this answer, would fund fsck_apfs -y /dev/disk2. Doing it this way and finally got a clean disk.